# How getrandom syscall guarantees randomness

Tags: cryptography, system-calls

I've read recently topics about cryptography, and seen the importance of randomness of the seeds in different algorithms.

And after reading `getrandom` manpage, It says that the random buffer will be taken based on an environment of the kernel, I want to know how exactly this is done, I could guess that the clock may be part of this environment, and maybe other hardware parts that I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is done by using low-order bits of a high-resolution clock whenever 'external' events happen -- external in this case being events that are not governed by the same clock domain.  So things like keystrokes and network packet arrivals are good choices.